# Unable to validate token: Couldn't retrieve remote JWK set

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect, adfs, jwk

I'm setting up an authentication method on Nexus Hybrid Access Gateway based on OpenID Connect, using ADFS as an identity provider. 
The goal is to access Nexus Hybrid Access Gateway using the OpenID Connect authentication method.

When configuring OpenID Connect on Nexus HAG I specified the following informations for the Identity Provider :

```
 - Cliend ID : 3b6fc4cc7463......
 - Client Secret : 812e4167.... 
 - Discovery EndPoint : https://example.com/adfs/.well-known/openid-configuration
```

When I try to log in to Nexus HAG portail using the OpenID Connect authentication method, i'm redirected to "https://example.com/adfs/ls/idpinitatedsignon" page to specify user credentials. ADFS is able to verify my credentials, but on my server (Nexus) I keep having this message:

> AUTHENTICATION_MECHANISM:[ 14 ] MECHANISM_MESSAGE:[ Unable to validate
>   token: Couldn't retrieve remote JWK set: Connection reset ]
>   RADIUS_REJECT_MESSAGE:[ Unable to validate token: Couldn't retrieve
>   remote JWK set: Connection reset ]

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks.